# When does ASP.Net MVC4 Error Handling Work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I don't understand why error handling built into MVC4 is so . . . fragile?

There's this code:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

and there's this entry in the web.config (system.web section):

```
<customErrors mode="On"></customErrors>
```

and an Error.cshtml that looks like this:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error";
}
<div class="container form-container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1">
        <h1 class="error">Error</h1>
        <h2 class="error">An Error Has Occurred</h2>
        <p>We apologize for the inconvenience.</p>
        @{
        if (Model != null && Model.Exception != null)
        {
            <h3>Exception</h3>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Exception.Message))
            {
            <p>@Model.Exception.Message</p>
            }
            else
            {
            <p>No Excepetion Message was provided.</p>
            }
            @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Exception.StackTrace))
            {
            <h3>Stack Trace</h3>
            <p>@Model.Exception.StackTrace</p>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <h3>Exception was null</h3>
        }
        }
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and when I try to force an error like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Testing");
    return View();
}
```

I get the yellow screen of death:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error 
  Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to "Off".



<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.



<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? It must be something fundamental. For the record, the very first test I tried worked and I haven't been able to make it work since. I don't know of any change I've made to break it.

Comment: Do you ever call `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters`? Check your global application class (global.asax or global.asax.cs). And don't assume it's fragile. Often times it's something silly that *you* (the developer) has misconfigured.

Comment: Yes, FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); is called in the Application_Start(). Like I said, it worked in my first test.

Comment: Try setting `customErrors="Off"`. Perhaps there's some logic that's causing a second exception, and by viewing the underlying error you can diagnose that.

Comment: @mason, yes, I've tried all of the possible settings: On, Off, and RemoteOnly. They all give yellow screens of death. "On" just gives the least amount of information. I've also looked to make sure that there are no other <customError> tags in other web.config files. There aren't.

Comment: @mason, I've also tried it with and without the default _Layout. Same results.

Comment: @VicF Yes, I know they give YSOD's. I'm interested in what it says when it's "Off".

Comment: @mason, when it's "Off," the error message is "Testing," which is the message in the ApplicationException I'm throwing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's the "@" in front of the if statements in the Razor code block. That's bad syntax.